# Can we create procedures for views in ODI 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle-data-integrator

**Can we create procedure for views in Oracle data integrator 11g ?** 
As I am aware of procedure in Oracle Data Integrator (ODI) to create and populate a relational table.

Can any one suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "create procedure for views"? I'm not sure I understand. Maybe you could add some SQL example of what you want to achieve in ODI. Do you want a procedure that create views?

Comment: Yes for creating procedures for views. As my source is SQL views.

Comment: "creating procedures for views" still doesn't mean anything. Please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve. What is the input, what is the output?

Comment: This is the target command:INSERT INTO AIF_OPEN_INTERFACE (
BATCH_NAME,
COL01,
COL02,
DESC1,
COL03,
AMOUNT
)VALUES (
:employees,
:entity_id,
:department_id,
:employee_category,
:account,
:amount
).

Comment: My source is SQL view and target is AIF_OPEN_INTERFACE table. I wanted to push the data from views to AIF_OPEN_INTERFACE tables using procedures in ODI . Is it possible?Thanx

Comment: Of course it is possible, you can add views as datastores in model like you do with tables. And then you use them in interfaces or mappings (in 12c). But for a simple process like this why do you want to use ODI procedure? Interface/Mapping would be a more suitable solution.

Comment: Since  views are your source datastores you can also hardcode them into your procedure code "select * from AIF_VIEW" but this is not suggested way for ODI usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ODI procedure and add a new step. In the *Properties* pane for that step, expand *Target Command* and choose the Technology of you database (for instance Oracle) and select the right Logical Schema. Then in the *Command* box you can type your SQL query :

```
INSERT INTO AIF_OPEN_INTERFACE (BATCH_NAME, COL01, COL02, DESC1, COL03, AMOUNT)
    SELECT BATCH_NAME, COL01, COL02, DESC1, COL03, AMOUNT FROM MY_VIEW
```

Make sure the schema used for connexion in the dataserver has INSERT privilege on AIF_OPEN_INTERFACE.

If the source data is coming from another dataserver, you will need to use a different approach to move the data from source to target dataserver. One of them is to use the query you posted in comment for the Target command, and a Select on the view for the Source Command.
Target Command :

```
INSERT INTO AIF_OPEN_INTERFACE ( BATCH_NAME, COL01, COL02, DESC1, COL03, AMOUNT )
    VALUES ( :employees, :entity_id, :department_id, :employee_category, :account, :amount )
```

Source Command:

```
SELECT BATCH_NAME, COL01, COL02, DESC1, COL03, AMOUNT FROM MY_VIEW
```

However, I would recommend using an interface instead of a Procedure. You can reverse-engineer your view into the ODI model and use it as a source in an interface.

Alternatively, you can use an interface with the *IKM SQL as a Source*. It becomes interesting if you reuse the same query in more than one mapping.
You can find more information and a download link here : https://blogs.oracle.com/warehousebuilder/entry/odi_11g_simple_flexible_powerful

Comment: Thanx Experts that was helpful for me.